# How to logout from a Domino Web app when login is OIDC?

Tags: lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

When using Domino for authentication, I would provide a logout link with `../names.nsf?logout` and the user would be logged out.

In a new system, using an OIDC login (MS Entra), I want to provide the same logout capability.  How do I do this?

I am running Domino version 12.0.2.  I can see from the documentation that version 14 provides for back channel logout for OIDC, but I am not sure if this is something different to what I am talking about.

Comment: At the moment there unfortunately is no way to do this.... hopefully they will implement the logout feature soon in Domino

Comment: That's pretty poor from HCL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenID Connect (OIDC) family of specs supports logout (from a single application) and global (or single) logout (from all applications that the user has logged into through the OpenID Provider, OP). With OIDC, you have the option of

- [OpenID Connect Session Management 1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html)
- [OpenID ConnectFront-Channel Logout 1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html)
- [OpenID Connect Back-Channel Logout 1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html)

for logout.

With Domino 14, OIDC back-channel logout is supported. Back-channel logout requests are accepted on the Domino server's callback URL -- either `/names.nsf?OIDCLogin` or `/auth/protocol/oidc`.
See [What's new in Domino 14? - Web user login with OIDC enhancements](https://help.hcltechsw.com/domino/14.0.0/admin/wn_webuserloginoidc.html).

If you prefer Front-Channel Logout, you need to register the logout endpoints for all your applications with [Azure AD Application registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-web-app-sign-user-sign-in?tabs=aspnetcore#application-registration). Then you need to add code to your application that listens for logout requests from other applications and logs the user out when a request is received.

```
const config = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "your_app_id",
    redirectUri: "your_app_redirect_uri", //defaults to application start page
    postLogoutRedirectUri: "your_app_logout_redirect_uri",
  },
};
const myMsal = new PublicClientApplication(config);
// you can select which account application should sign out
const logoutRequest = {
  account: myMsal.getAccountByHomeId(homeAccountId),
};
myMsal.logoutRedirect(logoutRequest);
```

The code above is from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1532499/entra-id-openid-single-sign-out where you can also find more info.